# Basic java input-response

Tags: java, input

So I am very new to java and I am trying to get this basic piece of code working. As you can probably tell below i am just trying to have it give the response i have set based on the user input on the temperature.

But no matter the input number that is given it only gives back the last response "Its freezing outside, Im staying in".

```
package ass4package;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 {

  private static Scanner scan;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("Enter current temperature :");

      scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int i = scan.nextInt();
      double temperature = 0;
      for (; i < temperature; i++)      
        if (temperature <= 200 & temperature >= 90) {            
          System.out.println("It is really hot outside, we should go to the pool");                            
        } 
      if (temperature <= 89 & temperature >= 70) {    
        System.out.println("We should have a bbq today");                          
      } 

      if (temperature <= 69 & temperature >= 50) {                
        System.out.println("I should wear jeans today");                           
      } 

      if (temperature <= 49 & temperature >= 30) {                
        System.out.println("I should wear a coat today");           
      } 

      if (temperature <= 29 & temperature >= 10) {                
        System.out.println("It is probably snowing, I should grab my sled");       
      } 

      if (temperature <= 10) {                
        System.out.println("Its freezing outside, Im staying in"); 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would it print out anything else? You delcare `double temperature = 0;` and then never change the value anywhere. Also, you may want to chain your statements with `else if`.

Comment: When i take out double temperature = 0; it gives me the error "temperature cannot be resolved to a variable" Sorry very new to java so i probably sound very dumb with this lol

Comment: That's definitely not the way to be going about it. Consider removing the for loop for now (it really doesn't serve a purpose, at lease at this point) and put the user input in your `temperature` variable with [`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29). I'd suggest getting your if statement figured out and properly structured, then play with the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped alot

Comment: No worries. Have fun learning!

Comment: @DrewKennedy suppose your point is correct. no point of having a `for loop` otherwise he wants user to keep asking for input.

Answer (score 0):

Because you var temperature always be 0 mate

Answer (score 0):

Your `temperature` variable suppose to have assigned the user input. But assigned to 0.

Also what is the point of having a for loop ?

You need this code only to test your task.

```
System.out.println("Enter current temperature :");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int temperature = scan.nextInt();

                if (temperature <= 200 & temperature >= 90) {            
               System.out.println("It is really hot outside, we should go to the pool"); 

              } else if (temperature <= 89 & temperature >= 70) {      
               System.out.println("We should have a bbq today");

              } else if (temperature <= 69 & temperature >= 50) {                  
               System.out.println("I should wear jeans today");

              } else if (temperature <= 49 & temperature >= 30) {                  
               System.out.println("I should wear a coat today");

              } else if (temperature <= 29 & temperature >= 10) {                  
               System.out.println("It is probably snowing, I should grab my sled");

              } else if(temperature <= 10) {                  
               System.out.println("Its freezing outside, Im staying in");
              }
```

But I think if you want user to keep entering input better use it inside a `while`. hope this helps.

Comment: @DevinP hope this helps. please (+1) if its solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the many issues of your code.
- First,   you need to add the else keyword from the second sub statement if statement of  an if statement ;
- Second, the  braces of the for (; i < temperature; i++) block are not well placed, so I removed this block ;
-Third, the   for (; i < temperature; i++) block will never be executed if i the value entered by user is greater that 0

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Enter current temperature :");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            double temperature = can.nextDouble();

              if (temperature <= 200 & temperature >= 90) {            
               System.out.println("It is really hot outside, we should go to the pool"); 

              } else if (temperature <= 89 & temperature >= 70) {      
               System.out.println("We should have a bbq today");

              }else if (temperature <= 69 & temperature >= 50) {                  
               System.out.println("I should wear jeans today");

              } else if (temperature <= 49 & temperature >= 30) {                  
               System.out.println("I should wear a coat today");

              }else if (temperature <= 29 & temperature >= 10) {                  
               System.out.println("It is probably snowing, I should grab my sled");

              }else if (temperature <= 10) {                  
               System.out.println("Its freezing outside, Im staying in");

              }
        }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of user input when you have `double temperature = 0;` always initialized to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i got it to work on my end